# Could an object be created in old generation?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

As a newly created object is allocated to new generation. Is it possible a newly created object is allocated directly to an old or tenured generation ? if it is, then on which bases ?

Comment: You're not supposed to worry or care about how the garbage collector works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See "[Frequently Asked Questions about Garbage Collection in the HotspotTM JavaTM Virtual Machine](http://java.sun.com/docs/hotspot/gc1.4.2/faq.html)":

> *Do objects ever get allocated directly into the old generation?*
>
> In 1.4.1 there two situations where allocation may occur directly into
>   the old generation.
>
> If an allocation fails in the young generation and the object is a
>   large array that does not contain any references to objects, it can be
>   allocated directly into the old generation. In some select instances,
>   this strategy was intended to avoid a collection of the young
>   generation by allocating from the old generation.
>
> There is a flag (available in 1.4.2 and later)
>   l-XX:PretenureSizeThreshold= that can be set to limit the
>   size of allocations in the young generation. Any allocation larger
>   than this will not be attempted in the young generation and so will be
>   allocated out of the old generation.
>
> The threshold size for 1) is 64k words. The default size for
>   PretenureSizeThreshold is 0 which says that any size can be allocated
>   in the young generation.
>
> In 1.4.2 case 1) the 64k word threshold continues to be true for the
>   incremental collector (-Xincgc). For the default collector and the
>   concurrent collector (-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC) the threshold value has
>   been changed so that an attempt to allocate into the old generation
>   only occurs if the size of the allocation is larger than the entire
>   young generation (available space when it is empty). It was observed
>   that there were cases where the 1.4.1 strategy for the default
>   collector and concurrent collector were leading to full collections
>   only (no young generation collections were being done). We deemed that
>   bad enough to raise the threshold.

Comment: this isn't correct absolutely, checkout here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24618467/size-of-huge-objects-directly-allocated-to-old-generation/24618819?noredirect=1#comment38154886_24618819