# Size of Huge Objects directly allocated to Old Generation

Tags: java, memory-management, garbage-collection, jvm, objectsize

Recently I've been reading about object allocations in different generations in Java. Most of the times new objects are allocated in Eden (part of Young Generation) and then they're promoted to Old Generation if any of the following criteria are met.

(1) Object's age reached the tenuring threshold
(2) Survivor space (to) is full when objects are being copied from                                  Eden (or) another survivor space(from)

But there's also a special case in which objects are directly allocated in the Old Generation instead of being promoted from the young generation. This happens when the object that we're trying to create is huge (possibly of the order of few MBs).

---

Is there any way to know the size/limit of the huge/humongous objects? I'm aware of the humongous objects criteria for G1 Garbage Collector. I just want to know the size limit **before or in Java 6**.

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Keep in mind that the GC code may also be sensitive to object type.  Some classes are known to typically be long-lived and thus are more apt to go straight to tenured status.

Comment: @HotLicks.. can you be more specific on these long-lived classes.. a small example will do :)

Comment: @Arkantos - It's been over 5 years since I worked in the JVM, and longer since I had water cooler discussions with the GC guys, so nothing's coming to mind at the moment.  I'm thinking some of the internal JVM classes fell into this category -- stuff related to processes and files -- but I don't have a specific example, and there's no telling how stuff has morphed over the years.  One thing I didn't hear discussed that would make sense is profiling classes and identifying those apt to be long-lived in a given app.

Comment: But a general point is that one should not assume that any decision about tenuring is black and white based on a single criterion.  The JVM may have several criteria and the algorithms may change at the whim of the GC developer.

Comment: Another point (somewhat less general) is that the reason for allocating huge objects directly into tenured space is that the Eden space is (by design) relatively limited in size, and allocating huge objects there would lead to excessive GC frequency.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The maximum size of an object HotSpot JVM may allocate in young generation is nearly as large as the size of Eden (YoungGen minus two Survivor spaces).

That's how the allocation rougly looks like:

1. Use Thread Local Allocation Buffer (TLAB), if `tlab_top` + `size` <= `tlab_end`
   This is the fastest path. Allocation is just the `tlab_top` pointer increment.
2. If TLAB is almost full, create a new TLAB in Eden and retry in a fresh TLAB.
3. If TLAB remaining space is not enough but is still to big to discard, try to allocate an object directly in Eden. Allocation in Eden is also a pointer increment (`eden_top` + `size` <= `eden_end`) using atomic operation, since Eden is shared between all threads.
4. If allocation in Eden fails, a minor collection typically occurs.
5. If there is not enough space in Eden even after Young GC, an attempt to allocate directly in Old generation is made.

Comment: @JigarJoshi A leftover from long ago, I suppose. In our days performing an extra parameter check on every object allocation would be an overkill.

Comment: sounds like a bug in doc, Thanks for your great explanation

Comment: Thanks for such a simple and elegant answer. +1 for keeping it simple :)

Comment: @apangin.. i've added my answer backing your analogy here.. Let me know if there's anything i need to add..

Comment: @Arkantos That's fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

You can set the limit by using following flag

```
XX:PretenureSizeThreshold=size
```

its default value is `0` I assume that by default if you don't set it it doesn't get considered with value=`0`, that means by default there is no maximum value that acts as threshold, by default object gets promoted only based on number of GC survival

HotSpot version

```
java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
```

to get all vm options (supported) you can run

```
java -XX:+PrintVMOptions -XX:+AggressiveOpts -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal  -version
```

and then you can refer to [hotspot vm option document](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html) or google particular option if not listed

---

```
byte[] array = new byte[300*1024*1024];

for(MemoryPoolMXBean memoryPoolMXBean: ManagementFactory.getMemoryPoolMXBeans()){
    System.out.println(memoryPoolMXBean.getName());
    System.out.println(memoryPoolMXBean.getUsage().getUsed());
}
```

outputs:

```
$ java -Xmx1500m -Xms1500m -Xmn500m -XX:PretenureSizeThreshold=100000000 -XX:+PrintGCDetails JVMMemoryInspection
Code Cache
393664
PS Eden Space
330301752
PS Survivor Space
0
PS Old Gen
0
PS Perm Gen
2749520
```

Comment: Awesome :) this is what I'm looking for. As you mentioned 0 is the default value. I checked the value from -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal on my laptop and its 0 and I even tried with jinfo running a sample program but its still 0. Let me try this on an actual application server box and get back to you. May be in a long running application, this value might have been changed by the JVM using ergonomics.

Comment: yes might be changed by ergonomics on server class machine

Comment: Also If you can point to any resource/link for some documentation on what these JVM flags actually mean/do. It'll be real time-saver :) thanks again..

Comment: `PretenureSizeThreshold` is not used unless specified explicitly in the command line. But even if set, it is checked only in slow allocation path. JIT-compiled code first tries to allocate in TLAB or in Eden before falling to slow path.

Comment: @apan cool, it would be interesting to see this in action if you could post a snippet that supports this

Comment: @JigarJoshi The test is as simple as
`byte[] array = new byte[300*1024*1024];` Run java with `-Xmx1500m -Xms1500m -Xmn500m -XX:PretenureSizeThreshold=200000000 -XX:+PrintGCDetails` to see what happens. Basically, `PretenureSizeThreshold` is just ignored and the object is allocated in Eden. If you set `-Xmn` to 400m, the array will not fit in Eden and will be allocated directly in Old Gen.

Comment: @apan you are right, the option comment is confusing then

Answer (score 5):

**JVM flags:**

-Xms1G -Xmx1G -Xmn500m -XX:PretenureSizeThreshold=100000000 -XX:+PrintGCDetails

By fixing the young generation size to 500MB, eden comes around 384MB, So any object greater than 384MB goes directly into OldGen and object less than 384MB is allocated in Eden itself. You can find the generation usages below

**byte[] array = new byte[400*1024*1024];**

```
PSYoungGen      total 448000K, used 30720K  
    eden space 384000K, 8% used  
    from space 64000K, 0% used  
    to   space 64000K, 0% used      
 ParOldGen       total 536576K, used 409600K  
   object space 536576K, 76% used
```

**byte[] array = new byte[300*1024*1024];**

```
 PSYoungGen      total 448000K, used 337920K  
  eden space 384000K, 88% used  
  from space 64000K, 0% used  
  to   space 64000K, 0% used  
 ParOldGen       total 536576K, used 0K 
  object space 536576K, **0% used**
```

For 400MB allocation, eden usage is 8% where as old gen usage is 76%
For 300MB allocation, eden usage is 88% where as old gen usage is 0%
So its clear that all the objects whose size is greater than the eden will be allocated directly into old gen.

Thanks apangin & Jigar for your valuable insights :)
I think -XX:PretenureSizeThreshold is not considered at all.