# How JVM ensures thread safety of memory allocation for a new object

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, jvm, new-operator

Let's assume this is about to happen in a true parallel environment, one VM, at the same time:

```
// Thread 1:
  new Cat()

// Thread 2:
  new Dog()

// Thread 3:
  new Mouse()
```

How does JVM ensure thread safety of memory allocations on heap?

Heap is one for all threads and it has its own internal data.

For simplicity assume a simple compacting garbage collector implementation, -XX:+UseSerialGC
-XX:+UseParallelGC, with simple incremental pointer to mark a start of free space and one continuous free space in Eden (heap).

There must be some kind of synchronization between threads when heap space is allocated for *Cat*, *Dog* and *Mouse* instances otherwise they can easily end up overwriting each other. Does that mean that every **new** operator hides inside some synchronized blocks? This way, many "lock free" algorithms are not in fact completely lock free ;)

I assume that memory allocations are made by the application thread themselves, synchronously, not by another dedicated thread(s).

I am aware of [TLAB](https://blogs.oracle.com/jonthecollector/entry/the_real_thing)s, or Thread Local Allocation Buffer. They allow threads to have a separate memory areas in Eden for allocations, so no synchronization is required. But I am not sure if TLAB is set by default, it is somewhat very obscure HotSpot feature. Note: do not confuse TLAB and `ThreadLocal` variables!

I also assume, that with more complex garbage collectors, like G1, or non-compacting garbage collectors, more complex heap structure data has to be maintained, like list of free blocks for CMS, so more synchronization is needed.

**UPDATE**: Please let me clarify this. I accept answer for HotSpot JVM implementation and variants with and without active TLAB.

**UPDATE**:
According to [my quick test](https://bitbucket.org/espinosa/a-java-core-playground/src/04e89d1f6004c888bb5fece2994f787d68766137/src/my/code/concurrency/c05/tlab/CreateObjectsInThreadsRun.java), **TLAB are set ON by default**, on my 64-bit JDK 7, for Serial, Parallel and CMS garbage collectors, but not for G1 GC.

Comment: It just does.  Giving each thread its own "zone" or "pool" is one way.  But some sort of locking protocol will generally be used for large objects that are allocated from a single pool.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've briefly described the allocation procedure in HotSpot JVM in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24620205/3448419).
The way how an object is allocated depends on the area of the heap where it is allocated.

#### 1. TLAB. The fastest and the most frequent way.

TLABs are the areas in Eden reserved for thread-local allocations. Each thread may create many TLABs: as soon as one gets filled, a new TLAB is created using the technique described in #2. I.e. creating of a new TLAB is something like allocating a large metaobject directly in Eden.

Each Java thread has two pointers: `tlab_top` and `tlab_limit`. An allocation in TLAB is just a pointer increment. No synchronization is needed since the pointers are thread-local.

```
if (tlab_top + object_size <= tlab_limit) {
    new_object_address = tlab_top;
    tlab_top += object_size;
}
```

`-XX:+UseTLAB` is enabled by default. If turn it off, the objects will be allocated in Eden as described below.

#### 2. Allocation in Eden (Young Generation).

If there is not enough space in TLAB for a new object, either a new TLAB is created or the object is allocated directly in Eden (depending on TLAB waste limit and other ergonomics parameters).

Allocation in Eden is similar to allocation in TLAB. There are also two pointers: `eden_top` and `eden_end`, they are global for the whole JVM. The allocation is also a pointer increment, but atomic operations are used since the Eden space is shared between all threads. Thread-safety is achieved by using architecture-specific atomic instructions: [CAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap) (e.g. `LOCK CMPXCHG` on x86) or [LL/SC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load-link/store-conditional) (on ARM).

#### 3. Allocation in Old Generation.

This depends on GC algorithm, e.g. CMS uses free lists. Allocation in Old Generation is typically performed only by Garbage Collector itself, so it knows how to synchronize its own threads (generally with the mix of allocation buffers, lock-free atomic operations and mutexes).

Comment: OK, looks like a winner. Just one more thing, if TLAB is not active, objects are allocated directly on Eden as described in section 2? Please could you update your answer? Thanks.

Comment: There's also escape analysis that leads to allocation on the stack.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann There is no such thing as 'allocation on the stack' in HotSpot. I've described this in the [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25562143/3448419).

Comment: @apangin You're splitting hairs over an implementation detail that might even change in the future.

Comment: @apangin why could CAS ensure thread safety if 2 different threads happen to allocate same size in heap?

Comment: @scottxiao Since CAS is an atomic operation. Only one thread at a time may increment the current heap pointer. The allocation size does not matter.

Answer (score 5):

This isn't specified in the Java specification. This means each JVM can do it however it wants to as long as it works and follows Java's memory guarantees.

A good guess on how this works with a moving GC, would be each thread gets its own allocation zone. Where it does a simple pointer increase when allocating objects. Very simple and very quick allocation with no locking. When that is full either it gets a new allocation zone allocated to it, or the GC moves all live objects to a continuous part of the heap and returns the now empty zones back to each thread. I am not sure if this is how it is actually implemented in any JVM, and it would be complicated with GC synchronization.

Comment: Very very unlikely. There is almost certainly a synchronization step.

Comment: @EJP, there _is_ a synchronization step implicit in what Smith_61 proposed.  A thread would have to lock a mutex each time it used up its current allocation zone.  (Note: I'm not claiming to know how Oracle's JVM or any other JVM actually does allocation.)

Comment: @EJP - By using a zone/pool the system only needs to synchronize when the zone/pool needs to be refreshed.  I can assure you this is how it's done in some JVMs.

Comment: Ugh - so signaling a 10MB object to another thread means copying it?

Comment: @MartinJames Each allocation zone/pool is local to a specific thread. Meaning all of the free memory is owned by the thread. Each object that was allocated from the zone is global.

Comment: @Raedwald Yes. It's the simplest one I could come up with that didn't require a lot of explanation.

Comment: @MartinJames - There's no need to copy an object to "signal" it to another thread.  Doesn't matter where/how the object was allocated.

Comment: Hot Licks is right, objects are not copied just because another thread may access them. Objects are copied from the young generation during garbage collection. But a 10MB object won’t be copied even then. Compare with http://www.kdgregory.com/index.php?page=java.outOfMemory#miscFailures “*if your object is large enough, it will be created directly in the tenured generation*”