# Is it possible to force JVM to create an object in stack other than heap?

Tags: java, jvm, heap-memory, stack-memory

I read some where that sometimes JVM will identify some objects and try to create it in stack than heap as the memory allocation on the stack is cheaper than the memory allocation in the heap, deallocation on the stack is free and the stack is efficiently managed by the run-time.
So is how this object allocation in stack works and is there any way to force the JVM to do this ?

Comment: Nobody can not control the JVM's oplects placement policy. Persistant data could not be placed on stack, because data on stack will be released after execution of certain classes.

Comment: For reference: http://www.stefankrause.net/wp/?p=64

Comment: Note that, even when stack allocation happens eventually, it does so only for the code paths detected as "hot" and worthy of JIT-compilation.

Comment: It always confuses me when people use a VM platform such as Java which takes great care to hide these low level details from you so you can focus on what is important (the application), and then they want to care about those details anyway. If you want control, don't use a high level VM-based platform such as Java.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no way to force the JVM to allocate objects anywhere. You should not care where Java actually allocates your Object because it is not defined in the specifications. That being said the JVM has gotten a lot smarter and using a technique called [escape analysis](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/performance-enhancements-7.html#escapeAnalysis)
it can, if it wants to, allocate an object on the stack. There is however no way to force the JVM to allocate an Object at a specific place and it is not required by the specification that this behavior happen.

Answer (score 6):

If talk about HotSpot JVM, it never allocates Java objects on a stack. However there is an optimization: when Escape Analysis can prove that an object reference does not escape the scope being compiled, JIT eliminates an allocation at all and replaces the object fields with the local variables.

*Note:* we cannot claim this an allocation on a stack since the object does not exist, e.g. calling Object's methods like `hashCode` or `wait` is not possible.

Whenever JVM can eliminate the allocation, it does so automatically.
If it cannot - there is no way to force it.

Comment: Your note is false: we may very well call `hashCode` on the Object, and even `wait`, and it won't make a difference to Escape Analysis, because EA needs to be sure *anyway* of the exact object type to rule in stack allocation. When you know the exact object type, you can inline all its method calls, and when you do that, you can make their implementations refer to the stack locations.

Comment: BTW `wait(timeout)` on a non-escaped object can be implemented as simple `sleep(timeout)`; a similar thing can be done for no-arg `wait()` call---infinite blocking.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Your theoretical assumptions are correct, but I'm talking now about concrete implementation, namely HotSpot JVM. Well, an abstract JVM can allocate objects anywhere and anyhow, but HotSpot will not eliminate the allocation if the object header is referenced.

Comment: And what about lock elision? If locking is elided, then header is not referenced when calling `wait()`. I suppose there is yet more subtlety making your point about `wait` correct when applied to the current version of HotSpot. Either way, this shouldn't apply to calling `hashCode()` on an object which overrides the default `hashCode()`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Yes, if `hashCode` is overriden, the object can be still subject to elimination. The same for locks over a non-escaped object. My point is that *"on-stack allocation"* is not the right term, since there is no actual "allocation", but rather a replacement of fields with local variables. I.e. such variables are subject to further optimizations: they can be held in registers or even folded as constants. We can equally well name this like "in-register allocation" :)

Comment: Yes, I have no contention with the basic point of the answer, and have already personally witnessed the machine code fitting your description.