# How many cpu cycles an object creation takes in java?

Tags: algorithm, jvm, heap-memory

I am curious how many cpu cycle or time does it takes to create an object of class that has no field in java? I was disscussing it with colleague whether it would be good idea to create new object for unique way to reffer something or create uuid, in his defence he said that creating object is very light weight in java these days, which I also agree.

But question is how can it compare to something completely different like uuid generation?

Hence, the doubt how much cpu cycles does it takes to allocate object & what are exact steps involved?

Comment: It takes less than 10 ns. A UUID takes much, much longer.

Comment: Most accounts of the cost of object creation don't cover the cost of garbage collection to recover storage later, or the expansion in the size of the resulting memory size to make garbage collection feasible, which may or may not figure in the total resource consumption that you are actually charged for or care about. But in any case most UUID routines will end up creating an object to return to you holding the UUID in any case so the UUID solution can be no cheaper, no matter what the cost of object creation is.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, thanks for time; but would like to understand how many steps it takes. And this would happen for millions request per second.

Comment: @mcdowella Is primitive declaration also same as object allocation? if no then in that case will it be faster or slower than object allocation, so i can use some thing faster than uuid that is also faster than object allocation

Comment: @Shashank There is no standard number of "steps", you can benchmark how long this takes on your machine, however micro-benchmarks tend to be a significant underestimate as creating an object means creating garbage and this slows down memory access in general as your caches don't work as efficiently.  In short, how much it slows down your application depends on context. I wouldn't call UUID millions of times per second unless that is all your program does.

Comment: @Shashank a primitive tends to be an order of magnitude faster than a simple object, but it depends on how it is used. A UUID takes about two orders of magnitude longer than creating an object.

Answer (score 7):

**Object creation in Java may take anywhere from zero to billions cycles.**

- Zero: when an object does not escape a local scope, JIT compiler may replace an allocation with local variables as a result of the allocation elimination optimization.
- Billions, because *any* allocation may trigger (potentially long) garbage collection.

I've already given a high-level overview of allocation in HotSpot JVM in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25512146/how-jvm-ensures-thread-safety-of-memory-allocation-for-a-new-object/25515423#25515423) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24618467/size-of-huge-objects-directly-allocated-to-old-generation/24620205#24620205) answer.

**The most common way to allocate an object in TLAB involves the following steps:**

1. Load `tlab_top` pointer (there is typically a dedicated CPU register for thread locals on x64).
2. Increment it by the size of an object.
3. Compare `tlab_top + object_size` against `tlab_end`. Jump to the slow path if needed.
4. Store the new value of `tlab_top`. The previous value is the address of newly created object.
5. Set the default header of the object.
6. Set the `klass` field - the pointer to object's class metadata.
7. Initialize the rest object data with zeros. Even an object without fields may have an alignment padding.

These all is about 10-15 CPU instructions.

**Let's measure the average time of an object creation with [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) benchmark.**

```
package bench;

import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Benchmark;

public class Alloc {

    @Benchmark
    public Object baseline() {
        return "Some preallocated object";
    }

    @Benchmark
    public Object newObject() {
        return new Object();
    }
}
```

Results:

```
Benchmark        Mode  Cnt  Score   Error  Units
Alloc.baseline   avgt   10  3,428 ± 0,089  ns/op
Alloc.newObject  avgt   10  4,505 ± 0,056  ns/op
```

So, the object allocation along with benchmarking overhead takes ~4.5 ns or around 11 cycles on a 2.4GHz CPU. That's indeed cheap comparing to UUID generation algorithms.

Comment: I've got the similar results: single digit ns per object. What I don't understand is if access to memory (latency) takes around 40ns, how would object creation take less than that?

Comment: @Abidi There is no synchronous access to main memory, since the line is already preloaded in CPU cache, thanks to prefetching.

Comment: I tried with a write to a global volatile after creating an object and it's still in single digit ns, you would expect sfence making CPU to flush its store buffers in order to have object created in heap instead of somewhere in the cache block?

Comment: @Abidi That's not how cache coherency is achieved. Application does not need to wait synchronously until data gets into main memory.