# Understanding object allocation in Java

Tags: java, performance, object, dynamic-memory-allocation, jit

I'm using Ubuntu 14 64 bit, Intel Core i5.

I wrote the following simple program to understand how object allocation works in Java:

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int i = 0; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++)
            testObjectCreationCompiled();
    }

    public static void testObjectCreationCompiled() {
        Object obj = new Object();
        if (obj.hashCode() == System.nanoTime()) {
            System.out.print("");
        }
    }
}
```

I run this program as follows:

```
java -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:CompileCommand=print,*App.testObjectCreationCompiled -server -jar target/test-1.0.0.jar
```

After looking at the compiled code I was wondering how the object allocation happened here (fragment of compiled code):

```
  0x00007f60651165e4: mov     %r12d,0xc(%rsi)   ;*new  ; - com.test.App::testObjectCreationCompiled@0 (line 13)

  0x00007f60651165e8: mov     (%rsi),%r10
  0x00007f60651165eb: mov     %r10,%r11
  0x00007f60651165ee: and     $0x7,%r11
  0x00007f60651165f2: cmp     $0x1,%r11
  0x00007f60651165f6: jne     0x7f606511662a
  0x00007f60651165f8: shr     $0x8,%r10
  0x00007f60651165fc: mov     %r10d,%ebp
  0x00007f60651165ff: and     $0x7fffffff,%ebp
  0x00007f6065116605: test    %ebp,%ebp
  0x00007f6065116607: je      0x7f606511662a    ;*invokevirtual hashCode
                                                ; - com.test.App::testObjectCreationCompiled@9 (line 14)

  0x00007f6065116609: movabs  $0x7f6079d5d440,%r10
  0x00007f6065116613: callq   %r10              ;*invokestatic nanoTime
                                                ; - com.test.App::testObjectCreationCompiled@13 (line 14)

  0x00007f6065116616: movsxd  %ebp,%r10         ;*i2l  ; - com.test.App::testObjectCreationCompiled@12 (line 14)

  0x00007f6065116619: cmp     %rax,%r10
  0x00007f606511661c: je      0x7f6065116649    ;*ifne
                                                ; - com.test.App::testObjectCreationCompiled@17 (line 14)

  0x00007f606511661e: add     $0x10,%rsp
  0x00007f6065116622: pop     %rbp
  0x00007f6065116623: test    %eax,0x15f3d9d7(%rip)  ;   {poll_return}
  0x00007f6065116629: retq
  0x00007f606511662a: nop
  0x00007f606511662b: callq   0x7f6065046020    ; OopMap{off=144}
                                                ;*invokevirtual hashCode
                                                ; - com.test.App::testObjectCreationCompiled@9 (line 14)
                                                ;   {optimized virtual_call}
  0x00007f6065116630: mov     %eax,%ebp
  0x00007f6065116632: jmp     0x7f6065116609
  0x00007f6065116634: movabs  $0x100000f28,%rsi  ;   {metadata('java/lang/Object')}
  0x00007f606511663e: nop
  0x00007f606511663f: callq   0x7f6065100fa0    ; OopMap{off=164}
                                                ;*new  ; - com.test.App::testObjectCreationCompiled@0 (line 13)
                                                ;   {runtime_call}
```

Here is the `new Object()` is marked as just `mov %r12d,0xc(%rsi)`.

It looks like the memory was already allocated at this point with the address at `r12d`.

The question is why do we `mov` the address to `[rsi+0xc]` memory location.

But as far as I know to allocate some memory in linux we have to perform `sys_brk` syscall. What we do here is just simple `mov` instruction, I dont see any `syscall` here ever. Why simple `mov` means `new Object()`?

How does object allocation work in JVM?

Comment: JVMs normally allocate large blocks of memory with `malloc` (probably using your sys_brk) and then partition out smaller parts of that large block for individual objects.  Probably the first block of memory was allocated long before the code above executed, and you didn't notice the system call.

Comment: @markspace Sort of compiler optimization? But is it possible to track it somehow? Otherwise it sounds like some magic. Can you advice some tools maybe?

Comment: Yes, an optimization because many small calls to `malloc` take much more time than one single call.  There's no way to track individual object creation in Java, you have to give up that kind of byte-by-byte thinking when you use a JVM.  To track overall memory, look at tools like VisualVM, jmap and jstat.

Comment: Simple programs aren't very suitable for understanding complex things. Trying to understand Java through C++ "glasses" is also a bit harmful angle. You're resorting a bit too much to the compiled code instead of studying the *theory* behind Java's workings.

Comment: @Kayaman The problem is I did not find any official documentation of how HotSpot JIT compiler works... It seems to me that the only way to understand it is sources or just decompiling code...

Comment: I've been under the impression that Hotspot is quite well documented and open. Of course if you're looking for easy and quick answers, you'll probably be disappointed. However if you're looking for easy and quick answers I have to wonder why you've picked such a specific and complex area to study? Have you gone through these: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-jsp-136373.html

Comment: @Kayaman Actually have not looked at this documentation yet. Very interesting, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The given fragment is incomplete. The actual allocation code should be right above this fragment.

`mov %r12d,0xc(%rsi)` is the last instruction of allocation sequence - it just zeroes the last padding word of the new object.

I've already decribed how object allocation works in HotSpot in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24620205/3448419), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25515423/3448419) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38298326/3448419) answers. You won't see any syscalls there since JVM does not rely on system allocator. It uses its own memory management in the preallocated region - Java Heap.

Here is how allocation sequence typically looks like in C2-compiled code. The comments are mine.

```
    mov    0x60(%r15),%rdx        ; obj = currentThread.tlab_top
    mov    %rdx,%r10
    add    $0x10,%r10             ; r10 = obj + sizeof(java/lang/Object)
    cmp    0x70(%r15),%r10        ; if (r10 >= currentThread.tlab_end)
    jae    0x00000000030ad2f4     ;     goto slow_case
    mov    %r10,0x60(%r15)        ; currentThread.tlab_top = r10

    prefetchnta 0xc0(%r10)        ; prefetch memory next to tlab_top into CPU caches
                                  ; to make subsequent allocations faster

    mov    $0x200001e5,%r10d      ; r10 = VMKlass of java/lang/Object
    shl    $0x3,%r10
    mov    0xa8(%r10),%r10        ; r10 = Header prototype for java/lang/Object
    mov    %r10,(%rdx)            ; obj[0] = r10 (header prototype)
    movl   $0x200001e5,0x8(%rdx)  ; obj[8] = VMKlass of java/lang/Object
    mov    %r12d,0xc(%rdx)        ; obj[12] = 0 (padding to 8-byte boundary)
```