# Will GC happen when a TLAB(Thread Local Allocation Buffer) is full?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

TLABs are allocated in Eden, a TLAB will be allocated when a thread first requires an object, so what happens when a TLAB is full(or maybe nearly full) ? Will another TLAB be allocated for the thread if there is still enough space in Eden or it just trigger a GC ?

Comment: What do you imagine to be the most efficient ;)

Comment: @Peter Lawrey Just allocate a new must be more straight forward.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/24620205/3448419

Answer (score 2):

When the current TLAB fills up, another TLAB will be assigned.  No need to perform an eden GC until eden reaches an occupancy threshold.