# Automatically promoting an object to Old Generation

Tags: java, object, memory, garbage-collection, heap-memory

An object can be promoted from Young Generation to Old Generation when it reaches the Tenuring Threshold or when the "TO" Survival Space is full when it is being transferred.

Therefore, my question is: In order to *improve performance*, if I know my object will be frequently used (referenced), **is it possible to automatically/manually declare an object in Old/Permanent Generation** so that not declaring it in the *Eden* would delay the necessity of *Minor Garbage Collection*, thus delaying the *"Stop The World" event and improving the applications performance*?

Comment: Of course without using the `MaxTenuringThreshold=0`

Comment: Young gen pauses should be fairly cheap, they should not have a big impact on application performance. If you're having an actual performance problem instead of just attempting some premature optimization then maybe you should state that instead.

Comment: What is your usecase? Generally in case of GC Tuning I have seen that  people are usually trying to solve the wrong problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Generally:**

No - not for a specific single object.

**In more detail:**

An allocation rougly looks the following:

1. Use thread local allocation buffer (*TLAB*), if `tlab_top + size <= tlab_end`. This is the fastest path. Allocation is just the `tlab_top` pointer increment.
2. If *TLAB* is almost full, create a new *TLAB* in the Eden space and retry in a fresh *TLAB*.
3. If TLAB remaining space is not enough but is still to big to discard, try to allocate an object directly in the Eden space. Allocation in the Eden space needs to be done using an atomic operation, since Eden is shared between all threads.
4. If allocation in the Eden space fails (`eden_top + size > eden_end`), typically a minor collection occurs.
5. If there is not enough space in the Eden space even after a Young GC, an attempt to allocate directly in the old generation is made.

**"Hack":**

The following parameter:

```
XX:PretenureSizeThreshold=size
```

This parameter is default set to `0`, so it is deactivated. If set, it defines a size threshold for objects to be automatically allocated into the old generation.

**BUT:**

You should use this with care: Setting this parameter wrong may change your GCs behaviour drastically. And: Only a few percent of objects survive their first GC, so most objects don't have to be copied during the young GC.

Therefore, the young GC is very fast and you should not really need to "optimize" it by forcing object allocation to old generation.

**Java parameters:**

If you want to get an overview over possible Java paramters, run the following:

```
java -XX:+PrintVMOptions -XX:+AggressiveOpts -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal  -version
```

This will print all flags you can set.

**Different garbage collectors:**

Also keep in mind that there are different garbage collectors out there, and that it is planned that *Java 9* should use the *garbage first (G1) GC* as default garbage collector, which again may handle big objects differently (by allocating them into *humangous regions*).

**Additional source:**

Stack overflow question: [Size of Huge Objects directly allocated to Old Generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24618467/size-of-huge-objects-directly-allocated-to-old-generation)

Comment: This is indeed possible but it comes with a footnote. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/systems/index-156457.html

Comment: @SurbhiSharma: `The option - XX:PretenureSizeThreshold=<byte size> in the concurrent collector that can be enabled to indicate the threshold for direct creation in the older generation. This could effectively be used for creation of caches, lookup tables, etc. which are long lived and do not have to go through a promotion cycle of being created in the younger generation and then being copied to the older generation. Use this option with care, since it can degrade performance instead of improving it.` All that's stated regarding *PretenureSizeThreshold* in that post is also part of my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create an object directly in old generation, it has to go through the *eden space* and *survivor spaces* (the young generation) before reaching the old generation. However, if you know that your objects are long lived (For example if your have implemented something like a cache) you can set the following JVM parameters:

`-XX:InitialTenuringThreshold=7`: Sets the initial tenuring threshold to use in adaptive GC sizing in the parallel young collector. The tenuring threshold is the number of times an object survives a young collection before being promoted to the old, or tenured, generation.

`-XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=n`: Sets the maximum tenuring threshold for use in adaptive GC sizing. The current largest value is 15. The default value is 15 for the parallel collector and is 4 for CMS.

Source: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html

So, you can reduce the application's tenuring threshold.
I actually did this and the stop the world GC time reduced for minor GC ( I had a huge 250GB JVM so the effect was quite profound
).

Comment: That's not correct humongous objects can be directly created in the old gen.

Comment: Agreed, What I got out of the question was that the current objects were being allocated to the young generation,and how cloud those objects be safely put into the old Gen? Safely being the key word here.Also another assumption i made here was that he wanted to avoig stop the world time be it in any generation GC .You can always  use PretenureSizeThreshold to directly create the object in Old gen, But does this really increase performance? NO. Accoding to my experiments it decreases it.Gets junk into the old gen and eventually triggers an old gen GC