# Average TLAB size grater than Average Object size

Tags: jboss, jvm

i'm with a big doubt about TLABs and objects.
For what i've studied about TLABs in JVM, the objects should preferentially kept into TLABs when they're created, going to the young generation, right?
However, as you can see in the image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUCm8.png), the 'Average TLAB Size' is **20,13 kB** for my application and 'Average Object Size' (outside TLABs) is **11,25 kB**.

As far as I know the objects should be saved into TLAB, unless they're greater than a TLAB. I'm afraid that we're having a lot of heap fragmentation, as you can see that we have the 'Total Memory Allocated for TLABs' with **52,90 MB** and 'Total Memory Allocated for Objects' with only **1,27 MB**. That is a waste of **51,63 MB** for only 5 minutes running the Java Mission Control.

Is it something very wrong with my application, JVM or JBoss? Or is that a misunderstood?

Thanks in advance.

[TLABs greater than Objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUCm8.png)

Comment: I don't see any problems in the given picture. 1,27 MB is the size of obejcts allocated **outside** TLAB. There is no sence in subtracting it from TLAB size.

Comment: The problem is: if I have an average size of objects allocated outside TLABs of 11,25 kB, and an average TLAB size of 20,13 kB, isn't that wrong?
Because an object with 11 kB should be inside a TLAB which has 20 kB, or am I wrong?

Comment: Imagine a half-full TLAB of 20 kB. It has already 10 kB allocated. Obviously, 11 kB object won't fit into remaining space, so it will be allocated outside TLAB (the remaining TLAB space is too large to discard).

Comment: See [how HotSpot JVM allocates objects](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24620205/3448419)

Comment: But, how can I know that I have half-full objects occupying 10 kB?

Imagine that I have 100 objects with an average size of 11 kB and TLABs of 20 kB size.
All of them should be in 1 TLAB each, right?

What I'm supposing is that, if I have objects being created with 11 kB size, so new TLABs should be created, or am I wrong?

Comment: TLAB size is not constant, it adapts dynamically to the workload. Also allocation policy is not straightforward, it considers many factors including TLABAllocationWeight, TLABWasteTargetPercent, TLABRefillWasteFraction, TLABWasteIncrement.