# why the gc parameter MaxTenuringThreshold doesn't work

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I wanna check the behavior for MaxTenuringThreshold when gc

this is my vm arguments:

```
-verbose:gc -Xms20M -Xmx20M -Xmn10M -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+UseSerialGC -XX:SurvivorRatio=8 -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=15 -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution
```

and this is my program:

```
public class TestTenuringThreshold {
    private static final int _1MB = 1024 * 1024;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte[] allocation1, allocation2, allocation3;

        allocation1 = new byte[_1MB / 4];
        allocation2 = new byte[4 * _1MB];
        allocation3 = new byte[4 * _1MB];
        allocation3 = null;
        allocation3 = new byte[4 * _1MB];
    }
}
```

as I have set MaxTenuringThreshold to 15, I think the allocation1 will be in the from space, but the result is:

```
[GC[DefNew
Desired survivor size 524288 bytes, new threshold 1 (max 15)
- age   1:     750416 bytes,     750416 total
: 5188K->732K(9216K), 0.0041173 secs] 5188K->4828K(19456K), 0.0041663 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
[GC[DefNew
Desired survivor size 524288 bytes, new threshold 15 (max 15)
- age   1:        136 bytes,        136 total
: 4913K->0K(9216K), 0.0018490 secs] 9009K->4827K(19456K), 0.0018711 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
Heap
 def new generation   total 9216K, used 4260K [0x00000000f9a00000, 0x00000000fa400000, 0x00000000fa400000)
  eden space 8192K,  52% used [0x00000000f9a00000, 0x00000000f9e28fd0, 0x00000000fa200000)
  from space 1024K,   0% used [0x00000000fa200000, 0x00000000fa200088, 0x00000000fa300000)
  to   space 1024K,   0% used [0x00000000fa300000, 0x00000000fa300000, 0x00000000fa400000)
 tenured generation   total 10240K, used 4827K [0x00000000fa400000, 0x00000000fae00000, 0x00000000fae00000)
   the space 10240K,  47% used [0x00000000fa400000, 0x00000000fa8b6dd8, 0x00000000fa8b6e00, 0x00000000fae00000)
 compacting perm gen  total 21248K, used 2718K [0x00000000fae00000, 0x00000000fc2c0000, 0x0000000100000000)
   the space 21248K,  12% used [0x00000000fae00000, 0x00000000fb0a78a0, 0x00000000fb0a7a00, 0x00000000fc2c0000)
No shared spaces configured.
```

as you see, the from space is 0% used, why? My jdk version is: java version "1.7.0_79"

Comment: The `MaxTenuringThreshold` is a maximum, and the largest you can set this to is 15.  This doesn't mean the threshold can't be 1.

Comment: I guess there are already some objects prior to your allocations. Along with the default `TargetSurvivorRatio=50` that makes impossible to fit those into the second survivor (reported as `Desired survivor size 524288 bytes`). Please, try `Runtime.getRuntime().gc()` at the very start.

Comment: Allocations never happen in either of the survivor spaces, they always start in the eden (young-gen) space. I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: BTW Large object are always added straight into the tenured space. If you want to exercise the young generation, you need to create smaller/normal sized objects.

Comment: the SurvivorRatio is set to 8, and the young space is 10 totally, so eden is 8m, from is 1m and to is 1m. When execute allocation3 = new byte[4 * _1MB]; the eden space is not enough for allocation3, as 1/4 + 4 + 4 = 8.25m, more than 8m, so the first minor gc happens, the allocation1 will be put into from space and allocation2 will be put into tenured space, and then allocation3 put into the eden space. When execute allocation3 = new byte[4 * _1MB]; again, the minor gc happens again, the question is why allocation3 has been put into tenured space, how to define the TenuringThreshold exactly

Comment: I've tried yegodm's method, add Runtime.getRuntime().gc() at the very start, and the result shows that the from space is 25% used, I think you're right

Answer (score 0):

The MaxTenuringThreshold is a maximum for the tenuring threshold. However the JVM is free to choose a much shorter threshold such as 1.

> the from space is 0% used, why?

All the object you have are large so they go straight into the tenured space.  Any objects in the eden generation will be created in the normal running/startup of the JVM, not due to your code directly.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24620205/57695

I would strongly recommend moving off Java 7 to 8 or 9. Note: Java 10 will be released in 3 months.